# Subspace of Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A\subset X$.how to show  that the following statements are equivalent:

(I) For every $x\in A$, $x$ has a neighborhood $U\subset X$ such that $A\cap U$ is closed in $U$.

(II) $A$ can be written as the intersection of a closed set and an open set.

(III) $\bar{A}-A$ is closed

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the problem? What are the difficulties you are encountering?

Comment: Is this homework? Where does it come from?

Comment: I suggest proving equivalence in the order 3->2->1->3. The first two steps aren't that hard. NB for readers: neighborhoods are not assumed to be open in this problem.

Comment: Mohammed, it seems that quite a number of your questions have drawn comments on the lack of context and requests to provide the source of the problem -- I suggest that you take this to heart and start providing this information of your own accord. It's more fun to work on a problem when you know why someone is interested in it, and how difficult it's likely to be, and how reliable it is that it's well-posed. Also some people like to know whether it's homework, and the way you've been posting problems looks quite similar to people posting homework problems, though it seems you weren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Leonid's suggestion:

(III) $\Rightarrow$ (II): $\bar A$ is closed and $X-(\bar A-A)$ is open, and their intersection is $\bar A\cap(X-(\bar A-A))=\bar A\cap (A\cup(X-\bar A))=A$.

(II) $\Rightarrow$ (I): Let $A=C\cap U$ with $C$ closed and $U$ open. Then $U$ is a neighbourhood of every $x\in A$, and $A\cap U=C\cap U\cap U=C\cap U$; thus $U-(A\cap U)=U-(C\cap U)=U-C=U\cap(X-C)$, which is open, so $A\cap U$ is closed in $U$.

(I) $\Rightarrow$ (III): If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x\in A$ such that $A\cap U$ is closed in $U$, then $U$ is disjoint from $\bar A-A$; otherwise it would contain a point outside of $A$ each of whose neighbourhoods contains a point of $A$, so $U-(A\cap U)$ couldn't be open in $U$. Thus the union of all the open neighbourhoods contained in all these neighbourhoods for all $x\in A$ is disjoint from $\bar A-A$. It is open and contains $A$. If we add the complement of $\bar A$, which is open, we get the complement of $\bar A-A$, and as the union of two open sets this is open; hence $\bar A-A$ is closed.

Comment: I would like to ask whether the Hausdorff axiom is used. I may have missed it.

Comment: @Mohammed: Ah, good point, I intended to comment on that and then forgot. No, I don't think I used it.

Comment: @Joriki For $(I)\rightarrow (II)$, you are proving $\bar{A}^c$ and $A$ are both open. So $\bar{A}-A$ is closed? Did I miss anything?